# @queryparam value assignment in clientside

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have to invoke a restful Web-Service from client side java class.

I need to pass HashMap, Strings and it must return me a list of beans. 
I am using jersey restful web service

My REST service is like this:

```
@put

public List<MilestoneDetailsBean> getMPPReader(
        @QueryParam("username") String username,
        @QueryParam("projid") String projid,
        @QueryParam("mppfile") File file,
        @QueryParam("dbtemplate") Map<String,Integer> dbtemplate)
```

could some one help me with how could I:

1. assign  values to these query parameters in my client side java code
2. what type of produces and consumes parameter I should put for my Web-Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) depends on how you create the query. `QueryParams` are those parts of an URL behind the `?`: `?key=value&key2=value2`

So what you could do is to just append the keys and values to the request URL. Remember to encode the values.

Like: `http://mydomain/service?username=hage&projid=hello+world&mppfile=myfile.txt`

Map is not usable for this. [See here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html)

2) Dont't know. `Produces` definitely depends on how you want to return the data (as xml, json, etc) and `Consumes` depends on what data you want to send to the server

Generally, for the client there exists a Jersey client API. Didn't use it yet, but you might [look at it](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e609).